# read a column text data and put in a 3D array in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a column of data (mydata.txt) as below (27 rows):

```
1
2
3
.
.
.
25
26
27
```

and I want to read it from a text file and then put it in a 3D array of B with the size of 3x3x3. Can any one help me about it? 
Here is my codes which I just used for reading the data. I do not know that how I should put the read data into a 3D array of 3x3x3.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int input1;
    double input2;

    //Open file
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("mydata.txt"); //or whatever the file name is

    while(!inFile.eof())
    {
        //Get input
        inFile >> input1 >> input2;

        //Print input
        std::cout << input1 << " " << input2 << " ";
    }

    //Close file
    inFile.close();
    system ("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just use this codes to read the column (hope I went the true way) but I do not that how I should put it in a 3D array. #include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int input1;
    double input2;

    //Open file
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("mydata.txt"); //or whatever the file name is

    while(!inFile.eof())
    {
        //Get input
        inFile >> input1 >> input2;

        //Print input
        std::cout << input1 << " " << input2 << " ";
    }

    //Close file
    inFile.close();
 system ("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}

Comment: @Sam: You should edit the question and add the code there. It is almost impossible to read code in comments, and even if it was possible, that code is part of the question, and you should not expect everyone to read all comments.

Comment: @Sam: Why are you reading an `int` and a `double` when what you want is reading 27 `int`s? What is the data structure that you want to stored the read values into? How would you iterate over that structure? Those are the building blocks, once you know how to do each one of them, you just need to put them together

Comment: @ David: It is just a simple example, while my original data are double. The first 3 lines will be my first column in first plate and from 4 to 6 the second column. From 25 to 27 will be my third column in 3th plate of my 3D matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
int b[3][3][3];
for (int i=0; i<3 && !inFile.eof(); i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<3 && !inFile.eof(); j++)
    {
        for (int k=0; k<3 && !inFile.eof(); k++)
        {
            inFile >> input1;
            b[i][j][k] = input1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: then how I should check that for example b[3][3][3] is equal to 27 or not? Because as I am checking b[3][3][3], it gives me 1.69757e-31!!

Comment: This is C.  Your arrays are zero-indexed.  If you want the last element in all dimensions, you need to check `b[2][2][2]`.

Comment: woow, so if I want to use the new 3D matrix and for example say a=b(1:2,1:3,2:3), then how I should define them?